Dart - disable Future timeout
I know that you can do await myAsyncFunction().timeout(const Duration(days: 1)) to change the timeout.
However, this doesn't work. Sometimes I get an error message saying that this future was aborted due to a timeout after 20 minutes. What am I doing wrong?

can you describe more specific about your 20 mins problem?
